# Yii – “Model.id” not defined for CArrayDataProvider and CSqlDataProvider - keyfield

Tags: yii

In my controller I want to display all the users of an application so I have used this code:

```
    public function actionClientu($id)
    {
$model=$this->loadModel($id);
$appUsers= $model->users;

        $dataProvider=new CArrayDataProvider($appUsers);
        $this->render('clientu',array(
            'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
        ));

    }
```

but I have this error:

```
 "Undefined AppUser.id"
```

it refer to this line:

```
$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('AppUser', $appUsers);
```

Any help please ?

Comment: You may want to try `$dataProvider=new CArrayDataProvider($appUsers);`

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem ! here is the cause of the problem:
my model keyfield isn't named id and I haven’t defined which column should be used.

So I just have to set the keyField like this:

```
new CArrayDataProvider($users, array('keyField' => 'user_id'));
new CSqlDataProvider($users, array('keyField' => 'user_id'));
```